# How to query Application Insights with no workspace IDs in Azure Graph Explorer

Tags: azure

I want to list all app insights with no workspace IDs.

I run the following Azure Resource Graph query but am not sure if it displays all app insights with and without workspace ids. I really need to check if there are any app insights with NO workspace ids

resources
| where type == "microsoft.insights/components"
| where properties['WorkspaceResourceId'] == ""

Comment: Your current query works fine, you can also use this that gives same results: `resources
| where type == "microsoft.insights/components"
| where isempty(properties['WorkspaceResourceId'])
`

Comment: Or, if you want all resources using the classic mode: `resources
| where type == "microsoft.insights/components"
| where properties.IngestionMode != "LogAnalytics"
| project id, resourceGroup, properties.IngestionMode`

Answer (score 1):

Your query works fine, I doublechecked in my lab as I've just been busy migrating some old application insights to the new workspace enabled ones. If you want you can also add the resourcegroup for easy locating the resources in case you have a large environment:

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.insights/components" 
| where properties['WorkspaceResourceId'] == ""
| join kind=inner (
    resourcecontainers
    | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
    | project subscriptionId, subscriptionName = name)
    on subscriptionId
| project name, type, subscriptionName, resourceGroup
| order by subscriptionName asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this query in Azure Resource Graph Explorer:

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.insights/components"
| extend IngestionMode = tostring(properties.IngestionMode)
| summarize count() by IngestionMode
```

You'll get something like this. Anything non `LogAnalytics` is classic (i.e., without workspaceId).

[image]

To get full list of Classic resources run this query:

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.insights/components"
| extend IngestionMode = tostring(properties.IngestionMode)
| where IngestionMode != "LogAnalytics"
| order by id
```